# How to remove colon in Emmet+Stylus in JetBrains IDE

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, stylus, jetbrains-ide, emmet

How to remove colon in Emmet+Stylus in JetBrains IDE?

For example, I type `mb10 + tab` and get `margin-bottom: 10px`

but it mast be a `margin-bottom 10px` (without the colon `:`)

How to disable it?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gz63M.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently it is not possible unfortunately.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15575 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to be notified on any progress.

Answer (score 1):

the auto-completes that `emmet` give's you for somethings like `mb10` or `ovh` or `bd10` are coming from a **fuzzy search** result, and I'm almost sure that It's not editable (at least in an easy way)
but you can change somethings about `emmet`, and in your case
It's done in this way
**`CTRL + ALT + S`** (open's up settings panel)
go to the path **`editor > CodeStyle > liveTemplates`**
expand **`Zen CSS`**
scroll down and find **`mb`**, click on it
at bottem of *settings panel* you should be able to see a field called **Template text**
change It to this `margin-bottom $VALUE$;`
click on `ok` and it's done 
if you do **`mb + tab`** the output would be `margin-bottom ;` with the *caret* instead of **`$VALUE$`** , so you can insert it then and get out of it easily by `tab` key
 
but as I said , its not responsible for something like `mb10` , because it's referring to a fuzzy search